# SED replace in file

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to do a simple (I think) search and replace in a file.

Search for the test wrapped between `@{...}` and replace it with `%<...>`.

For example:

1. `@{SOMETEXT_A}`  becomes `$<SOMETEXT_A>`
2. `@{SOMETEXT_B}`  becomes `$<SOMETEXT_B>`
3. `@{SOMETEXT_C}`  becomes `$<SOMETEXT_C>`

I have this in sed which matches the search params,

```
sed -i 's/\@{.\*}/\$<.\*>/g' input.txt
```

..but doesn't copy the string to the result and instead results in

```
$<.*>
```

How do I copy over the regex match from ".*" into the replace string?

Many thanks

Comment: The `\*` in a regular expression means a literal `*`. You must have captured the text between the `@{` and `}` by enclosing the regular expression in parentheses, and then pasted the captured portion into the replacement text by using back references (e.g., `\1`). Then the substitution expression could be `s/@{\([^}]*\)}/$<\1>/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i 's/@{\([^{}]*\)}/$<\1>/g' file
```

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/U7MGCQ):

```sh
s='@{SOMETEXT_A}  becomes $<SOMETEXT_A>
@{SOMETEXT_B}  becomes $<SOMETEXT_B>
@{SOMETEXT_C}  becomes $<SOMETEXT_C>'
sed 's/@{\([^{}]*\)}/$<\1>/g' <<< "$s"
# => $<SOMETEXT_A>  becomes $<SOMETEXT_A>
#    $<SOMETEXT_B>  becomes $<SOMETEXT_B>
#    $<SOMETEXT_C>  becomes $<SOMETEXT_C>
```

The `@{\([^{}]*\)}` regex is a POSIX BRE compliant pattern that matches

- `@{` - a `@{` literal string
- `\([^{}]*\)` - Capturing group 1 (that is referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern) matching zero or more chars other than curly braces
- `}` - a `}` char.